# Internal DNS Setup [Bind9] , unable to dig from another machine, but able to dig locally

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, dns-zone

I have a local network with 3 machines, each one of them is able to ping the others.

I have setup a DNS server using bind9 in one of those machines, and asigned the `ftp.rp.ies`domain to one of its ip.
This is how my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks

```
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.222.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.222.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.222.2
    dns-search rp.ies

auto enp0s3:0
allow-hotplug enp0s3:0
iface enp0s3:0 inet static
    address 192.168.222.3
    dns-nameservers 192.168.222.3
    dns-search rp.ies

auto enp0s3:1
allow-hotplug enp0s3:1
iface enp0s3:1 inet static
    address 192.168.222.4
    dns-nameservers 192.168.222.4
    dns-search rp.ies
```

Lets focus on `enp0s3:1` , `192.168.222.4` , which Ive asigned to `ftp.rp.ies` in my zones files.

Now, locally I can `dig ftp.rp.ies` and it will resolve properly. But if I try to dig it from another server in my local network it returns the following error [error when doing dig from another machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqxDm.png)

My current `/etc/bind` configuration files looks like this:

db.rp.ies

```
    $TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA servidor.rp.ies. root.rp.ies. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
          IN      NS      servidor.rp.ies.
          IN      NS      ftp.rp.ies.
          IN      NS      web.rp.ies.
servidor          IN      A       192.168.222.2
cliente1          IN      A       192.168.222.51
router            IN      A       192.168.222.1
cliente2.rp.ies.  IN      A       192.168.222.52
ftp       IN      A   192.168.222.4
web       IN      A   192.168.222.3
server            IN      CNAME   rp.ies.
```

db.222.168.192

```
    $TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA servidor.rp.ies. root.rp.es. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
;
         IN      NS  servidor.rp.ies.
     IN  NS  ftp.rp.ies.
     IN  NS  web.rp.ies.
2        IN      PTR     servidor.rp.ies.
51       IN      PTR     cliente1.rp.ies.
1        IN      PTR     router.rp.ies.
52       IN      PTR     cliente2.rp.ies.
4    IN  PTR     ftp.rp.ies.
3    IN  PTR     web.rp.ies.
```

And finally this is how my resolv.conf looks

```
    nameserver 192.168.222.2
nameserver 192.168.222.3
nameserver 192.168.222.4
search rp.ies
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was residing in my client server, it was using the wrong dns so i changed it in `/etc/resolv.conf` to

```
nameserver 192.168.222.2 //this is my dns server, it was using a default one
search rp.ies
```

Also apparently my interfaces wasnt configured quite well, so I changed it to a single address.